# Angularjs and Java server - how to use the same port when running from Netbeans?

Tags: java, angularjs, glassfish, cross-domain-policy

I have Java RESTful application which deploys on Glassfish server when I am running it from Netbeans IDE. In this case, server URL looks like `localhost:8080`.

Also, I have angularjs application (HTML5 application) which runs on Embedded Lightweight server (I have figured out it in project properties). This application is available at `localhost:8383`.

The problem is, the cross-domain policy not allowing me to communicate between Client and Server, because ports are different. I can wrap angularjs app into WAR archive and deploy it on Glassfish - in this case, everything works fine. But it is very painful, because I need to debug my code and every time making archives will waste a lot of time.

So, is it possible to, maybe, auto-deploy my Client on Glassfish on every run or debug session?

Comment: Enabling CORS on your development glassfish server is not an option?

Comment: I use a reverse proxy server that serves static resources directly from the source files (partials, JS files, etc.), and proxies all the REST service requests to the app server.

Comment: @JBNizet can you explain please in details how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Make a filter in your server to enable CORS like this

```
headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:8383");
```